# How to redirect 404s that generated for css&JS files?

Tags: redirect, wp-redirect

I have 404s generated for a deleted CSS&JS files and i want to redirect the requests for those files in general. I mean a redirect for all 404 generated for CSS&JS files.

These errors are generated by google crawlers.
Please note that those files are generated randomly from a caching plugin `WP Fastest Cache` which generates different file names on every delete for the cached files.. some times i make some CSS changes so i always have to delete those files.

Answer (score 0):

Google crawlers just follow the HTML. If you intend on deleting CSS&JS files, search through all your themes&plugins that were using the files and either comment off or remove the line calling the CSS&JS files.

Look for both wp_register_???() and wp_enqueue_???().

Examples for plugins:

```
wp_enqueue_style('wp_css_name', plugins_url( '/assets/css/style.css' ... ));

wp_enqueue_script('wp_js_name', plugins_url( 'assets/js/script.js' ...)...);
```

Example for themes:

```
wp_register_style('normalize', get_template_directory_uri() . '/normalize.css'...);
wp_enqueue_style('normalize');
```

With all themes&plugins not calling for nonexistent files, your problem is solved.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i wanted to tell you that those file are generated randomly from a caching plugin which generates different file names on every delete for the cached files.. some times i make some CSS changes so i always have to delete those files.

Comment: Then clear cache every time you delete a file..

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to put redirects in place quickly, [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/quick-pagepost-redirect-plugin/) will let you specify the original url and the redirect url. Not sure if this will help you here, but it's worth mentioning.